# Converting from 3.1 to 4.0... gamestates

Tags: xna-4.0

I'm restarting development of a game I was working on, and have successfully converted it over to XNA 4.0 using the cheat sheet.  Most of it works, some of it doesn't, and I'm in the process of fixing what doesn't work.

One thing that I had was a state system that was heavily based on the state system used as an example of XNA Unleashed, the ebook.  I didn't have much in it.... basically just the ability to pause the game.

When I paused the game, the action of the game would stop, and the word "PAUSED" would appear in block letters across the screen, and you'd see the paused action.  However, now it seems that the sprite batch automatically clears out everything between frames, so when I pause the game now, the screen clears, leaving PAUSED over a purple background.  Back then, I believe that adding "SaveStateMode.SaveState" would prevent that from happening, but that functionality was removed.  When I did some research, I found out that it was removed because it was essentially useless, that's all handled in the game state manager.

However, I can't find any documentation on this.  Where should I start?  Right now, my code looks like this:

In the Playing Game State update method:

```
    if (input.WasPressed(0, Buttons.Start, Keys.Enter))
    {
        GameManager.PushState((GameState)ThisGame.PausedGameState.Value);
    }

    public void PushState(GameState newState)
    {

        AddState(newState);

        //Let everyone know we just changed states
        if (OnStateChange != null)
        {
            OnStateChange(this, null);
        }
    }

    private void AddState(GameState state)
    {
        states.Push(state);

        Game.Components.Add(state);

        //Register the event for this state
        OnStateChange += state.StateChanged;
    }

//PausedGameState Draw method:

    public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        ThisGame.SpriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, BlendState.AlphaBlend, null, null, null, null);
        DrawPaused();  //draws the Paused Text
        ThisGame.SpriteBatch.End();
    }
```

The goal is to make "PAUSED" appear over the screen, with a snapshot of where the gameplay left off... and not "PAUSED" over a cleared purple screen.

Comment: I think maybe your problem is elsewhere. The purple colour you are seeing is the default colour of an uninitialised buffer. This often comes up if you have a render target issue. Perhaps [this answer](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/40127/288) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Do you suppose that GraphicsDevice.Clear() somehow got called after the state changed to paused? What does the DrawPaused() method do in your code?

Comment: GraphicsDevice.Clear() never gets called in my code.  DrawPaused simply calls spritebatch.drawstring 5 times (4 to create a black border)

Comment: So why not still draw the game and all the sprites associated with it, except draw that first, then allow the DrawPaused() method to be called after the game has drawn itself in the background. Just prevent the Update calls for the game loop so that it essentially seems "paused" but the draw will still render the character, level, enemies, ect... at the locations they were at when the game was paused. Does that clash with what you are trying to do?

Comment: Sort of, then I would be not using game states the way that I am now.  Currently all of the stuff that you just mentioned is in the 'PlayingGameState' class.  Currently, I have a "PausedGameState" class.  I could get rid of that and move the pause function to the playing game state class, but that could, I imagine, get a little ugly when I add more states that use functionality a lot like the paused game state (menus, maps, etc)

Comment: I've always used polymorphism with my various "screens" in XNA. I created an interface (IGameScreen) that all of my screens had to implement. My main game loop would send update and draw calls to the active screen(s) based off my current states. This allowed me to isolate the code related to each screen and clean up the code quite a bit.

Comment: (didn't mean to hit enter... *sigh*) I was gonna say that I've never used the GameStates before so I am not sure that I can be useful to your question. Are the states built into XNA?

Comment: Yes they are.  I'm pretty sure that I'm going to have to refactor what I'm doing to more closely match what you are doing.  As I didn't do much development on my state system, I'm willing to call it a wash and implement something new.  Do you have any sample code I could see to better understand what you're doing?

Comment: I'll see what I can dig up. At very least I can make a simple demonstration for you that even has a working pause menu lol.